# how to install IBM dashdb ODBC driver for Windows 10 and connecting that to SPSS Modeler

Tags: odbc, spss, dashdb, spss-modeler

I'm trying to connect to dashDB through my SPSS Modeler stream with the database source node, but I'm at a total loss as to how to do it. I downloaded the DB2® v11.1 IBM Data Server Driver Package, but I don't know what to do next. Help, pls!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if the dashDB driver is included in the DB2 package, but you should be able to find it in the [dashDB™ driver package](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SS6NHC/com.ibm.swg.im.dashdb.doc/connecting/connect_driver_package.html) for your operating system. Also make sure that you are using the supported driver package as listed in the [Detailed System Requirements](http://www-969.ibm.com/software/reports/compatibility/clarity-reports/report/html/softwareReqsForProduct?deliverableId=D44C8050EEA711E4989B60FF8B09BCE8&osPlatforms=AIX%7CLinux%7CMac%20OS%7CWindows&duComponentIds=D002%7CS001&mandatoryCapIds=13&optionalCapIds=7%7C47%7C22%7C72%7C186%7C223%7C26) for your version of SPSS Modeler.

Once the driver is installed, you will have to create an ODBC data source and you will need to follow the instructions for your operating system on how to do that.